# How should I store and retrieve dictionary words

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-autocomplete

I have a JavaScript variable that holds an array of dictionary words like

```
var words = ['and','cat', n1, n2, n3 and so on ]
```

This array holds about 58020 words.

What i have done is created an auto complete jQuery plugin that displays the words from the dictionary array in a drop down list when the user starts typing text into the text box. But the browser crashes at some point because I think the looping through each word is making the process slow.

How can i overcome this?

Here is the function that checks the word array and outputs the words if found

```
$(textInput).keyup(function(e) {

            var text = $(this).val();
            var foundTag = false;

            for (var i = 0; i < settings.tags.length; i++) {

                var tagName = settings.tags[i].toLowerCase();
                if (tagName.startsWith(text)) {

                    if (text != '') {
                        foundTag = true;
                        $(settings.tagContainer).append(GetDivDropDownItem(settings.tags[i]));
                    }
                    else {
                    }

                }

            }

        });
```

### Edit

```
$(textInput).keyup(function(e) {

            var text = $(this).val();
            var foundTag = false;

            for (var i = 0; i < settings.words.length; i++) {

                var tagName = settings.words[i].toLowerCase();
                if (tagName.startsWith(text)) {

                    if (text != '') {
                        foundTag = true;
                        $(settings.tagContainer).append(GetDivDropDownItem(settings.words[i]));
                    }
                    else {
                    }

                }

            }

        });


var GetDivDropDownItem = function(text) {

        var cWidth = $(container).css("width");
        cWidth = cWidth.split("px")[0];

        var tag = $("<div/>");
        $(tag).css("paddingLeft", "5px");
        $(tag).css("paddingRight", "5px");
        $(tag).css("paddingBottom", "5px");
        $(tag).css("paddingTop", "5px");
        $(tag).css("width", cWidth - 10);
        $(tag).css("float", "left");

        $(tag).css("fontFamily", "Arial");
        $(tag).css("fontSize", "12px");
        $(tag).css("color", "#6A6B6C");
        $(tag).text(text);

        return $(tag);

    };
```

Comment: Is `settings.tags` the array of dictionary words?

Comment: Why not use one of the dozens of existing jQuery plugins for this sort of thing, rather then roll your own?   http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote  This for instance.

Comment: @JonathanM, yeah it is tags is the words

Comment: @asawyer i didn't think there were any, i will look now

Comment: If you define `$(settings.tagContainer)` as a variable before the for loop, this saves a lot of speed. What does `GetDivDropDownItem` do? And maybe do the `text != ''` test before looping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By not putting 58.000 words in a Javascript array.

Use a webservice that holds all the dictionary words in a database, and query that.

---

**edit:** If you really insist on storing this in a javascript array, group the words by their first two characters. Easy to implement and around 600 times faster already.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use better datastructures and algorithms. In general, I would suggest doing some research on pre-existing work before trying to tackle any problem.

This is an article that may be of help: http://orion.lcg.ufrj.br/Dr.Dobbs/books/book5/chap08.htm

Answer (score 3):

See this benchmarks and comparisons done by jQuery creator John Resig:

http://ejohn.org/blog/revised-javascript-dictionary-search/

Basically the answer is a simple trie structure, if you really want to do it pure-JS.

Answer (score 2):

A trie data structure would be good for a dictionnary.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `settings.tags` is the array of dictionary words, this code is going to be *very* cumbersome, since you're looping through the *entire* array with each `keyup` event.

I would suggest that you organize the dictionary words in a structure that allows you to go to the words very quickly. Perhaps a binary tree or just an associative array.